# Highlight code identifiers on a page dynamically when you hover over one of them

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, dom-events

I'd like to highlight identifiers on a page dynamically; when the user hovers over any variable or function name, all the other mentions of such variable or function must be highlighted.

I have my own parser that does code analysis and HTML generation, so, there's no need to figure out what is an identifier, that can all be pre-processed on the server, and the appropriate DOM IDs can be pre-assigned and such.

Can I use CSS alone, with any JavaScript, to accomplish such highlighting?  If not CSS, pure JavaScript might be ok, but CSS would be strongly preferred.  I hate slow web pages and CPU hogs, so, performance is very important to me, and I'd prefer to make such highlighting as fast as possible.

Comment: I'm almost entirely certain that this is not possible in CSS alone.

Comment: @JBux, but you can do appearing/disappearing menus with CSS, heck, someone even wrote a whole calculator with CSS!  This one surely shouldn't be as difficult as writing a calculator!

Comment: "as difficult as writing a calculator" It's not the difficulty writing a calculator but the sort of hacks involved in writing one. There's simply no reliable way to style all elements of a class when any of its members are hovered - if there's a hack for it, I'd like to know, but it'll probably be so unorthodox you'll start to question its performance impact for just how strange it is (of course, you could just profile it then...).